# Access denied when saving to file path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, error-handling

I have an upload method that looks like this

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    Component c = db.Components.Find((int)id);
    HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files["image"];

    if (photo != null && photo.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var file = IGT.imagePath + "\\Components\\";

        //bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(file));

        //if (!exists)
        //   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(file));

        var filename = file + id.ToString() + ".jpg";

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(file))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(file);
        }

        photo.SaveAs(filename);
        c.Image_Url = IGT.baseUrl + "/Content/images/Components/" + id.ToString() +".jpg";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But I receive the error at `photo.SaveAs(filename);` saying

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\chris\Source\Repos\inventory2.0\PIC_Program_1.0\Content\images\Components\498.jpg'
>   is denied.'

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: run it as admin, does it work there?

Comment: `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filename);` looks like just typing mistake - presumably you planned to create folder and then write file there?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes I changed it to 'file' so that it creates the Components folder. Then I wish to save the image there but still receive the same error message

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov nevermind I just tried it again and it worked. Not sure why it didn't work the first time but thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Whatever user is executing that code, does not have permission to write to that file path. If you go to C:\Users\chris\Source\Repos\inventory2.0\PIC_Program_1.0\Content\images\Components, right click, properties, Security tab, you will see the users that have permissions and what those permissions are. You can add or edit your users permissions there.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah I need the folder to give the user the correct permissions upon creating the folder programmatically

Comment: Good catch. But still could be an issue if he has read writes on that directory and it does exist already. Then the create would never get called. So "Totally not related" is a stretch.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I meant that if the folder already existed, the create would never be called. But I do agree that it is a fair assumption to say that this code probably created it and permissions probably aren't an issue.

Comment: @user1289451 actually you likely correct - folder already exist and since OP writes under user's account/anonymous it will not have permissions to save file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your application user don't have permission to access your the folder. If you are testing this in VS IIS express, then you should grant permission for your current user.

However, if you are receiving this error message from IIS Server. Then you should grant permission for application pool identity(IIS Apppool\apppoolname).

Process monitor can help you fix access denied error all the time. You just need to create a filter for Result ="access is denied". Then it will tell you who and what permission are required.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon